# Solaris 11 zone networking performance issues

Tags: networking, solaris

I'm working on automatically deploying Solaris 11 zones basically the same way laid out in [this blog post](https://blogs.oracle.com/maineoffice/entry/a_handy_recipe_for_a) with ipf running NAT and an internal etherstub network. On the global zone I get normal download speeds, but inside the zones I'm getting 3-4 kbps. Are there any specific gotchas which would cause this?

Comment: What are you downloading?  Do other protocols such as NFS have similar poor performance within the zone?  What does your CPU load look like when you're seeing such behavior?

Comment: CPU looks fine, I tested with both HTTP and HTTPS. The only case that is slow is via NAT, internal <-> global zone is full speed as is global <-> internet. Also I can only repro this running on Xen, VirtualBox and VMWare are both fine, so I think this must be a bug with NAT and some specific part of the virtio network drivers.

Comment: So you only have the problem in zones inside a virtual Solaris instance running on top of Xen?

Comment: That is correct, and only when the connection is going via NAT.